# Count number of times a script ran (sh shell)

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have to write a script that will display the number of times that the current user has executed the script, inclusive of the current execution. This value should persist across logins. Exit with status 1 if this was their first time running the script or else 0.

> For example:  Assume the name of script is runs.sh then,
>
> ```
> ./runs.sh ; echo $?
> 1
> 1
> ./runs.sh ; echo $?
> 2
> 0
> ./runs.sh ; echo $?
> 3
> 0
> ```

What I have done so far:

```
#! /bin/sh
temp= 0
count=$(( temp + 1 ))
echo "$count"
```

But I am always getting this output:

```
1
0
```

Not sure what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You're wondering why `0+1` is `1` every time?

Comment: Ohhhhh! I guess I have to use for loops? Not really sure how to implement loops in sh

Comment: Read a number from a file, add 1 and write it back to the file

Comment: In addition, you have to lock the file while updating, because the user might run several instances of the script in parallel.